# Event scheduler in Mysql after retrieving data from other table

Tags: mysql

I need retrive data from a table `employee` like

```
select empid, name, place, position, date_of_joining where status=active
```

Keeping the retrieved data in loop inside a scheduler. If the column named `position` is `Software engineer` and `date_of_joining` > 01-01-2010, then the empid, name, place, position must be saved in another table name `valid_employees`

How to write a scheduler for this?
I have never written schedulers before. I am new to the topic. Please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried anything ?

Comment: No. actually I am stucked in the beginning near the for loop itself. So I couldn't go further

Comment: have a look at this http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/working-mysql-scheduled-event/

Comment: @Hexana I understood how to create an event. But I am unable to write an event in which first data is retrieved using a select query and loop is rotated. In this loop the condition is checked and if condition is satisfied then only data must be inserted in other table

Comment: No need to create a loop, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

MySql documentation on [CREATE EVENT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html) describes exactly with examples how to set up an event within mysql.

Within the event body (after the DO) you neet to write an insert ... select ... statement that will transfer the records to the valid employees table. It will be something like this:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO valid_employees
    (empid, name, place, position, date_of_joining, status)
    SELECT (empid, name, place, position, date_of_joining, status) FROM employees
    WHERE status='active' and position='Software Engineer' and Date('2010-01-01')<date_of_joining
```

But I would consider creating a view on the employees table with the select above and then you do not have to create the event and transfer the data over to another table. This may be a more efficient solution, but we do not know the details to suggest which is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

The following statement creates a recurring event that executes every minute and is expired in 1 hour from its creation time.  Then Wait for 1 minute, check the table and see if a record was added:

```
CREATE EVENT test_event_03
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE
STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
ENDS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 HOUR
DO
    INSERT IGNORE INTO valid_employees
    (empid, name, place, position, date_of_joining, status)
    SELECT (empid, name, place, position, date_of_joining, status)FROM employees
    WHERE status='active' and position='Software Engineer' and Date('2010-01-01')<date_of_joining
```

Comment: How about checking an if condition in as different operations must be done for different condition. Like consider there is one more table called salary and a column salary_status. Also employees table has column salary_status. If the employees table salary_status is equal to salary table salary_status then update the